# ssh heroku error "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 "

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I am trying to ssh into heroku (access command line)...
I followed the instuctions in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys, but I keep getting this error:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

Entire log:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/gilad/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/gilad/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for heroku.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to heroku.com [50.19.85.132] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gilad/.ssh/ssh-dss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/gilad/.ssh/ssh-dss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/gilad/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/gilad/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version endosome
debug1: no match: endosome
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad
debug1: Host 'heroku.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/gilad/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/gilad/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to heroku.com ([50.19.85.132]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = he_IL.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = he_IL.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
shell request failed on channel 0
```

ssh_config:

```
Host heroku.com
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I really have on idea what this means -- help?

Comment: Try changing things and see what happens. Try walking through the guide again and see if that helps. Then, if you still can't get it, tell us what you tried and what didn't work. If you show an effort, people are more likely to help. Also, generally avoid "Entire log:" if you can while still asking a complete question. Skim over this article and it will help you to improve your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The PTY and shell request messages mean the server isn't willing to start an interactive session for you. That might be normal for Heroku. The Heroku page which you linked to is talking about using ssh for git access, which doesn't require PTYs or shells. What makes you think shell access should work?

Answer (score 2):

You can ssh into a heroku dyno by first installing [heroku toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line#download-and-install) and after logging on toolbelt, you can run `heroku run bash --app your_app_name`

See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#ssh-access) for heroku docs about it. Pay attention to their warnings though saying there is little to gain by using ssh